# Content disappears after user finishes entering groceries

Tags: javascript, jquery

Happy new year, everyone!  I'm celebrating by working on learning jquery. I added some jQuery to my code below and managed to add some content and change some css with it. The getGroceries function is working fine and is doing what it's supposed to do. When the user finishes entering the groceries, the program (printGroceries) is supposed to print the list that the user entered. That portion is also working.... HOWEVER, when that happens, the program removes the header (My grocery list) and removes all styling.

What am I doing wrong?

EDITED CODE: Deleted full code and added the portion that I changed (commented the old).

```
function printGroceries(groceryItems) {

if (groceryItems.length > 1) {
    $('grocery-list').html('<ol class="items" id="list-items">');
    //document.write("<ol>");
    for(x=0; x < groceryItems.length;x++){
    groceryItems;
    $('#list-items').prepend('<li>' + groceryItems[x] + '</li>');
    //document.write("<li>" + groceryItems[x] + '</li>');
    }
    $('#grocery-list').append('</ol>');
    //document.write("</ol>");
} else {
    $('#grocery-list').prepend('<p>Sorry, your list is empty.</p>');
    //document.write('<p>Sorry, your list is empty.</p>');
}
}
```

Problem: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vbJpG/)

Comment: You're using document.write which will obliterate your existing output. Why not use jQuery's functionality instead?

Comment: @LeeTaylor nailed the problem... can't use `document.write` after page has loaded

Comment: @LeeTaylor, freaking a! This is why I love/hate code! lol Thank you so much for the guidance. I've managed to output all those document writes by using `.append()`, `.prepend()`and `.html()` to add the messages before/after tags, and by completely changing the HTML code within some elements. YOU GUYS ROCK!

Comment: Also, Thank you @charlietfl for confirming, I really appreciate your assistance!

Comment: Your `if` condition seems to be wrong, it should be `groceryItems.length > 0`

Comment: Another problem seems to be `$('grocery-list').html('<ol class="items" id="list-items">');` should be `$('#grocery-list').html('<ol class="items" id="list-items">');`. You are missing the `#`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function printGroceries(groceryItems) {
    if (groceryItems.length > 0) {
        $('#grocery-list').html('<ol class="items" id="list-items">');
        //document.write("<ol>");
        for(x=0; x < groceryItems.length;x++){
        groceryItems;
        $('#list-items').prepend('<li>' + groceryItems[x] + '</li>');
        //document.write("<li>" + groceryItems[x] + '</li>');
        }
        $('#grocery-list').append('</ol>');
        //document.write("</ol>");
    } else {
        $('#grocery-list').prepend('<p>Sorry, your list is empty.</p>');
        //document.write('<p>Sorry, your list is empty.</p>');
    }
}
```

You have missed few things as I suggested in the comments 
1. The `if` condition should check `groceryItems.length > 0`
2. `$('grocery-list')` should be `$('#grocery-list')`, you are missing the **id selector** here

Solution: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vbJpG/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery; here's a version that takes advantage of `$.each()`. Also, it's best to build out your string and append only once rather that append each item over and over.

```
function printGroceries(groceryItems) {
  var listItems = '';
  if (groceryItems.length > 0) {
    $.each(groceryItems, function (i, item) {
      listItems += '<li>' + item + '</li>';
    });
    $('#grocery-list').append('<ol class="items" id="list-items">'+listItems+'</ol>');
  } else {
    $('#grocery-list').prepend('<p>Sorry, your list is empty.</p>');
  }
}
```